# How to compile the code below in one step using explicitly the files *.cpp on Linux / Windows operating system?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I would like to compile the source `mcb_cycle.cpp` found in https://github.com/deepai/Parallel-MinimumCycleBasis in the directory `mcb` in one step, directly from the files *.cpp. Is it possible? Could anybody help me in? I would be interested in compilation on both Windows and Linux operating systems.

Comment: What does "without object files" even mean? You compile the source files ("translation units") into object files. That is what compiling is. Compiling without object files just sounds like nonsense to me.

Comment: Ok, sorry, you are right. My question is related to compiling the code above in one step. In the Makefile the compiler g++ is called twice. I would like to reduce it into one step, using directly the files .cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward: `gcc mcb_cycle.cpp -o mcb_cycle`. (plus any other options you need).

Comment: Have you tried that? I don't think that it does work. My problem has been solved: the lines "include" corresponding to the header files of the standard libraries have been placed into the files stdafx.h.

Comment: @Roloka: I tried, of course with my own code. Has been working since at least 1996. As I said, " plus any other options**you** need - I can only guess at those two gcc calls. `#include "stdafx.h"` is a performance optimization for MSVC++ and harmless on GCC.